# GIT PULL is working but GIT PUSH isn't?

Tags: git

I'm having problems pushing to git.  Whenever I execute "git pull," it pulls from the repo I need.  However, when I execute "git push" after committing, I get the following error:

```
  Permission denied
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
```

I verified that my ssh key is accurate.  I only have one ssh key so I think it's unlikely that git is using the wrong key.  "git pull" works fine.  "My git config --list" shows the following:

```
  user.name=myusername
  user.email=myemail
  push.default=current
  remote.origin.url=theCorrectURL
  branch.thebranchiwannapushto.remote=origin
  branch.thebranchiwannapushto.merge=refs/heads/branchname
  mergetool.prompt=false
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have write permissions to this repository.

Comment: is your git repository hosted on github, bitbucket or any other server?

Comment: does everything look correct with your remote when you type git remote -v

Comment: otherwise you could try the following in the command line to fix any origin issues                      ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/github_rsa.pub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to configure push refs specifications to ensure the push is done to the desired branch. Maybe you only have push permission for certain branches.

Comment: Fine, but could you please explain how this is done?

Comment: In the repository's git config file `.git/config`. See also: [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec), [section in Atlassian's tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/refs-and-the-reflog#refspecs) and [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44333810/757308)

Comment: @dwilli if you're having this problem (like I did 5 years ago at my first internship), then more than likely someone who controls the repository needs to grant you write permissions to the repository.  For example, I can `git pull` the `facebook/react-native` `master` branch onto my computer, but I cannot push my changes to `master` (because I don't have write permissions)