# Telling from git fetch man page to being able to fetch a single branch

Tags: git, branch, fetch

This is a followup to:

[How do I fetch only one branch of a remote git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368987/how-do-i-fetch-only-one-branch-of-a-remote-git-repository)

Which references:

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html

And which relies on understanding the refspec pattern of usage of git fetch:

```
git fetch [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>…]]
```

To understand that usage pattern, an understanding of "refspec" is needed.  For example:

[Git - What is "Refspec"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333437/git-what-is-refspec)

The question which was asked was how to fetch a single branch (of a remote repository), with one popular answers:

```
git fetch <remote_name> <branch_name>
```

This answer is also popular:

```
git remote add -t <remote-branch-name> <remote-name> <remote-url>
```

My question is: How does one figure out how to reach that first form from the git fetch and refspec documentation?

I'm asking because "git fetch" is a very basic git operation, one of the starting commands for git beginners, and I'm finding myself at a loss to capture an adequate explanation of the command.

Comment: See "CONFIGURED REMOTE-TRACKING BRANCHES" in https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html. And `The format of a <refspec> parameter is an optional plus +, followed by the source ref <src>, followed by a colon :, followed by the destination ref <dst>. The colon can be omitted when <dst> is empty.`

Answer (score 0):

If you're updating the current branch the command is

```
git pull origin master
```

where `origin` is the name of remote repo and `master` is the name of the branch to be **fetched and merged into the current branch** (it's supposed the current branch is your local `master`).

For any other branch the command is

```
git fetch origin branch:branch
```

This fetches commits from the remote branch `branch`, update local remote-tracking branch `origin/branch` and update local branch `branch`.