# How to create and push tags with JGit

Tags: git, tags, push, jgit

I am using JGit to clone repository, make some changes in file, commit, tag it, and then push it to remote repository.

I have written code using JGit, which will clone repository, make some change in file, then commit the change, create new tag and push the commit and tag.

```java
Git git = Git.cloneRepository()
             .setURI("https://*****@stash.dts.*****.git")
             .setDirectory(outputFolder)
             .call();

// Some code to update the file
git.add().addFilepattern(".").call();

git.commit().setMessage("File Commit").call();

// Creating tag
git.tag().setName(version).setForceUpdate(true).call();

// Pushing the commit and tag
git.push().call();
```

After push, I expect the remote repository to show my change and new tag, but change with commitId is showing in remote repoitory but tag is not visible. It's showing 'No Tags'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To push all tags, you need to specifically enable this before calling the `PushCommand`.

For example:

```java
List<PushResult> pushResult = git.push().setPushTags().call();
```

Alternatively you can use `PushCommand::setRefSpecs` to set a list of [refspecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333437/git-what-is-refspec) that you wish to get pushed.