# What is the + for in a git refspec?

Tags: git, git-refspec

This https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec
says

```
The + tells Git to update the reference even if it isn’t a fast-forward.
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git - What is "Refspec"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44333810/5625547). The linked answer explains the `+` in some more depth.

Comment: The implied question here is "what does git mean by fast-forward", so does this answer your question? [What does "Git push non-fast-forward updates were rejected" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684352/what-does-git-push-non-fast-forward-updates-were-rejected-mean)

Comment: No. It doesn't explain what updating the reference means. Nor does it explain the alternatives to a fast-forward. It explains what "Git push non-fast-forward updates were rejected" mean.

Comment: So if you put the pieces together, you get your answer: It means "Do not reject non-fast-forward updates".

Comment: say `git help glossary` and look up fast-forward.

Comment: So by `update the reference even if it isn’t a fast-forward` it means `always update the reference`?

Answer (score 1):

As [Raymond Chen noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69740739/what-is-the-for-in-a-git-refspec#comment123277840_69740739), you must put together several pieces here:

- `+` sets the "force" flag, i.e., do the update even if the operation is not a fast-forward; and
- a *fast-forward* is a property of a *name update*.

The first part is pretty straightforward, but the second part can be kind of opaque.  It's a bit like [the first few paragraphs in Sherlock Holmes and the Adventure of the Dancing Men](http://esl-bits.net/Sherlock.Holmes/Return.of.Sherlock.Holmes/Dancing.Men/01/default.html).

A name, or *ref* or *reference* in Git, such as the branch name `refs/heads/develop`, contains one hash ID, usually that of a commit.  The notion of fast-forwarding only makes sense for refs that identify commits anyway, so from here on we shall assume this.

Commits, in Git, produce a [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) or DAG, because each commit stores the raw hash IDs of its *parent* commits.  We may apply a simple [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) algorithm on the individual commits to find this graph, for instance.  This means that each pair of nodes *in* the graph can have "precedes" (math-symbol `≺`, kind of a bendy less-than) relationships: *X ≺ Y* means that node *X* comes "before" node *Y* in the DAG.  If commits *P* and *C* are parent and child, then clearly *P ≺ C* and *C ≻ P* (C "succeeds" P).

Similarly,  If *PP* is the parent of *P*—the arrows go *⟵PP ⟵P ⟵C* in Git, as they point backwards instead of forwards—then *PP ≺ C* as well.  Here *PP* is the *grandparent* of *C*.

Because Git *finds* commits by starting at the commit to which some label points, then working its way backwards, if we take any set of commits:

```
... ⟵PP ⟵P ⟵C ...
```

and have some name like `develop` pointing to *PP*, and move that name "forwards"—against the direction of the internal arrows—to point to *C*, we can still *use* that name to *find PP*.  We just start from *C* now and work backwards two hops this time.

This kind of motion, where a name that used to find some commit now finds some *descendant* of that commit, is a *fast-forward operation*.  The resulting name motion does not "lose" any commits: it merely *adds all the descendants*.  This is true even if the name-motion is rather tangled.  For instance, suppose we have this, where each round `o` is a commit and the two `name`s are branch names:

```
          o--o--o--o--o
         /             \
...--o--o  <--name1     o  <--name2
         \             /
          o--o--o--o--o
```

We now propose to Git that it should move the name `name1` to point to the same commit as the name `name2`, giving:

```
          o--o--o--o--o
         /             \
...--o--o               o  <--name1, name2
         \             /
          o--o--o--o--o
```

All of the commits on the left-middle are still *reachable from* the name `name1`; it just requires going through either the top or bottom row.

Mathematically, then, if:

- *name* identifies commit *X* now;
- we ask Git to change *name* to identify commit *Y* instead; and
- *X ≺ Y* ("X precedes Y")

then this name-motion is a *fast-forward*.  For simplification purposes, if we ask Git to "move" from *X* to *X* (or equivalently, set *Y=X*), Git actually tests for *X ≼ Y*, but the idea should now be clear.

Hence, a reference update, as made by `git push` or `git fetch`, will work on a branch if:

- the update is a fast-forward, or
- the update is *forced*.

Thus, `+` forces non-fast-forward updates.

> "... in five minutes you will say that it is all so absurdly simple"